# XPath: get value using relative path (PHP, Symfony, DOMCrawler) error

Tags: symfony, xpath, phpunit, absolute-path

I'm writing a test to test my understanding of XPath with Symfony's DomCrawler:

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->add('<foo><foo>bar</foo></foo>');
$crawlerWithNodes = $crawler->filterXPath('/foo/foo');

$this->assertEquals('bar', $crawlerWithNodes->text());
```

But the above results in:

> InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.
>
> On line:
>
> $this->assertEquals('bar', $crawlerWithNodes->text());

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the content as `DOMDocument` instead of simple string (is interpreted as HTML).

You also need to add the _root prefix in the xpath string if you want to find an absolute path in the structure. See the `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Tests\CrawlerTest` cass for further example (testFilterXpathComplexQueries method)

Consider the following test method:

```
    public function testCrawlerAsHtml()
    {
        $crawler = new Crawler();
        $crawler->add('<html><body><foo><foo>bar</foo></foo></body></html>');
        //die(var_dump($crawler->html()));
        $crawlerWithNodes = $crawler->filterXPath('/_root/html/body/foo/foo');

        $this->assertEquals('bar', $crawlerWithNodes->text());
    }

    public function testCrawlerAsDomElement()
    {
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML('<foo><foo>bar</foo></foo>');
        $crawler = new Crawler();
        $crawler->add($dom);
//        die(var_dump($crawler->html()));
        $crawlerWithNodes = $crawler->filterXPath('/_root/foo/foo');

        $this->assertEquals('bar', $crawlerWithNodes->text());
    }
```

Hope this help